# Is there a way to push an 8 column div to the right without adding a 4 column div before it in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having to use empty divs around my layout to get what I need. For example

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-md-4"></div>
  <div className="col-md-8">
    <Article />
    <Article />
    <Article />
    <Article />
  </div>
</div>;
```

Is it possible to not use the `col-md-4` but get the same effect

Comment: What version of Bootstrap?  3 uses push and 4 obsoleted it.  If ver 3 then add col-md-offset-4 to your col-md-8 column.  I don't recall the ver 4 syntax off the top of my head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are "offset classes" for that, for example `class="offset-md-4"` will create a gap/offset over 4 columns before the current element.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/columns/#offset-classes

Comment: All tutorials I've seen used `col-md-offset-4` which didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to specify the number of columns to be offset using the col-md-offset-* class.

```
<div className="row">   
    <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
       <Article />
       <Article />
       <Article />
       <Article />   
   </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ml-auto` with `col-md-8`.
This works because the parent element has class `row` which adds `display: flex`.

PS. You can test the snippet only on full page.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row bg-secondary">
  <div class="col-md-8 bg-success ml-auto p-5"></div>
</div>
```